# Run two nodes with same identity or migrate identity to a new node

Tags: baking, node

Is it possible to run two nodes simultaneously with the same identity on the mainnet? Perhaps run one in private mode or something?

If not, is it possible to bootstrap a new node with a new identity and then copy my private keys from the old node to the new node and then restart my new node with my original accounts from the old node and resume baking?

Comment: The node and its network identity have nothing to do with your private keys and accounts. Private keys and accounts are not used by the node, only by clients (including bakers and endorsers). They are kept in the client dir, ~/.tezos-client. Do you want an answer which explains this confusion? Or would you like to rephrase the question? (What do you really want to accomplish?)

Comment: It is possible to move a baker and endorser to a new host, by moving the ~/.tezos-client dir. This could be a host which also runs a tezos-node, with a different (or migrated) network identity. (And, I suppose, there _must_ be a new tezos-node on the new host, for the baker.) You must be careful not to violate the double bake/endorse protection while moving the ~/.tezos-client dir. Is this the kind of thing you're asking about?

Comment: Thanks @Tom, that answers my questions.  Sorry for my confusion, I wasn't sure if the nodes identity was bound to the baker keys in some way but you've made it clear.

Comment: How about multiple PublicIP NICs on 1 node, where the same node identity appeared on multiple IP addresses?  Would nodes out there start blacklisting those IPs or that identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can either copy the contents of the tezos `client` directory to your other node(s), or you can run a [remote signer](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/introduction/various.html#signer) that all your nodes can use.